# How to check for http timout error in Go?

Tags: go, http, error-handling

New to go. This is currently my code:

```
client := http.Client{
    Timeout: 10 * time.Millisecond,
}
resp, err := client.Get("http://google.com/")
if err != nil {
    if os.IsTimeout(err) {
        fmt.Println("There was a timeout")
    }
    panic(err)
}
```

This works, but os.IsTimeout writes:

```
// This function predates errors.Is, and the notion of whether an
// error indicates a timeout can be ambiguous. For example, the Unix
// error EWOULDBLOCK sometimes indicates a timeout and sometimes does not.
// New code should use errors.Is with a value appropriate to the call
// returning the error, such as os.ErrDeadlineExceeded.
```

```
if errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded) {
    fmt.Println("There was a timeout 2")
}
```

Which doesn't work. I tried debugging, but there wasn't an easy way for me to see how to check for the specific error type. Coming from.NET I could directly see the exception type, and check for that, how do I go about this in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not do it this way nowadays and setting a timeout on the client is left as per the [api stability guarantee](https://go.dev/doc/go1compat).

Today, you'd set up a client and do a request with a [`context.WithTimeout`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout).

> TL;DR: The context will be "Done" if the request times out before a response is received and not be "Done" if the response is returned before the timeout is reached.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // Start a http server to test the timeout
    srv := setupServer()
    defer srv.Shutdown(context.Background())

    // Examle 1: Using a context with a timeout for a request
    // =======================================================

    // create a default http client
    client := &http.Client{}
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)

    // Release resources when done
    defer cancel()

    // Create a new request with our context
    req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", "http://localhost:8080/hellotimeout", nil)

    // Start a timer
    start := time.Now()
    // Make the request
    _, err := client.Do(req)

    // Check if the request was anything other than a timeout
    // Note that we could check for the timeout error here.
    // However, we will use a select statement to demonstrate how to handle the timeout.
    if urlErr, isURLErr := err.(*url.Error); isURLErr && !urlErr.Timeout() {
        log.Printf("Something went wrong: %s", urlErr)
        return
    }

    select {
    // If the request times out, the context will be done.
    // If the request is completed here, the context will not be done and the default case will be executed.
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Printf("Request timed out after %s", time.Since(start))
    default:
        log.Printf("Request completed after %s", time.Since(start))
        log.Println("Processing response...")
    }

    // Examle 2: The same, but this time the request does not timeout
    // ==============================================================

    // Create a new request with our context
    ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
    defer cancel2()
    req, _ = http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx2, "GET", "http://localhost:8080/hello", nil)

    // Start a timer
    start = time.Now()
    // Make the request
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    // Check if the request was anything other than a timeout
    if urlErr, isURLErr := err.(*url.Error); isURLErr && !urlErr.Timeout() {
        log.Printf("Something went wrong: %s", urlErr)
        return
    }

    select {
    case <-ctx2.Done():
        log.Printf("Request timed out after %s", time.Since(start))
        return
    default:
        log.Printf("Request completed after %s", time.Since(start))
    }
    log.Println("Processing response...")
    io.Copy(log.Writer(), resp.Body)
}

func setupServer() *http.Server {
    // Setup a server so we can test the timeout
    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080"}

    http.Handle("/hellotimeout", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Simulate a long running request
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
    }))

    http.Handle("/hello", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Respond immediately
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
    }))

    // Start the server in "background"

    go srv.ListenAndServe()
    return srv
}
```

<kbd>**[Run on playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iY8yfKZh8g5)**</kbd>

Comment: ´if urlErr, isUrlErr := err.(*url.Error); isUrlErr´ works for me. I don't see the benefit in the new API (tbh it seems worse), but maybe that's further along my go-path. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: @Peheje Well, you can pass a single context to multiple instances of whatever and by this, you can ensure that a whole operation involving multiple actions do not take any longer than your timeout. Now imagine you want to gracefully stop a whole slew of operations and think about how [`context.WithCancel(ctx)`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel) can help you here... And when you use `context` anyway, you can as well use `context.WithTimeout`.